# displaying pictures when tapping a tableview cell

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

i recently made a tableview filled with cells. i was wondering if i can, when i tap a cell display a certain picture instead of a blank screen

i tried linking cells with different image views but i can't do that using a tableview ,so what is the required code

i do know that I'm supposed to use the prepareForSegue statement

override  prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {}

i just don't know what to type

i only want to add an image display when i tap one of the cells

thanks for the help

Comment: So I assume you want to display the image of the cell in another UIViewController?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add another view controller in your storyboard which will be opened after tapping the cell.

In `tableView(_:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)` you have to remember which cell was tapped, and in `prepareForSegue` you can pass data to the destination view controller. In destination view controller just load the image based on data passed.

Comment: can you tell me what data to pass in

Comment: Depends on how your model is structured - it can be an index to an array, an URL to the image or the image name from assets.

Comment: its an index to an array

Answer (score 0):

You can use prepareForSegue to pass data from your cell to the next ViewController (the image one).

I would do something similar to this.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.indexTapped = indexPath.row
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goToImageViewController", sender: self)
}

....

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "goToImageViewController") {
        var vc = segue.destinationViewController as! ImageViewController
        vc.image = imageDatasource[indexTapped] as! UIImage
    }
}
```

Once you call `performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String?, sender: AnyObject?)` the transition will be automatically handled after executing the `prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)` code.

Comment: i tried what you said and it didn't work I'm pretty sure i did something wrong

Comment: can u simple it down a bit

Comment: So the idea is to pass information from the cell you are tapping to the next ViewController, so you'll be able to show up an image, right? If so, you just need to keep the index of the array in `self.indexTapped` and once in the `prepareForSegue(...)` set the desired image from your Array to the next ViewController (let's say your `ImageViewController`), ask me if you have any more doubts.

Comment: i get an error at vc.image it says it doesn't exist

Comment: That's because you'd probably did not create the `UIImage` attribute on the `ImageViewController`. Just go to `ImageViewController` and paste this line `var image: UIImage! = nil`, hope it helps.